# How to switch to BT headset while wired headset is plugged in

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

The problem is that wired headset it seems has priority higher then BT headset. So this snippet doesn't resolve the problem

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    

audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); // also tried with AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AudioTests.this, R.raw.test_cbr);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Kiryl : are you tring to send audio through bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

While it is hackish, directly reflecting on AudioSystem may give you access to this functionality.  I haven't yet implemented this, but I know that there are commercial apps which provide this ability (see the "SoundAbout" app in the market).

```
        Class reflectedAS = null;
        reflectedAS = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
```

Then, there is a function called "setDeviceConnectionState" that looks like it will do the trick.  If I get this working, I'll update the answer, but wanted to provide you a starting place (and for others as well who come across this).

Source code for AudioSystem: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/media/AudioSystem.java#AudioSystem

**Do not expect this to work on all versions of Android, or to be supported in future releases**

That said, not sure of another way to do this.